WPF DataContext загружает не те данные
У меня есть следующий ListView:
<ListView x:Name="NotificationInfo" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Notifications}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding date}" Header="Дата" Width="Auto" />
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding text}" Header="Уведомление" Width="Auto" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>

И класс со следующим описанием (в классе NotificationData только 2 и так указанных поля):
public ObservableCollection<NotificationData> Notifications { get; private set; } 
public NotificationsViewModel()
{
    Notifications = new ObservableCollection<NotificationData>
    {
        new NotificationData { Date = "111111", Text = "aaaaaaa" },
        new NotificationData { Date = "222222", Text = "bbbbbbb" },
        new NotificationData { Date = "333333", Text = "ccccccc" },
        new NotificationData { Date = "444444", Text = "ddddddd" }
    };

}

В конструкторе делаю так:
public TabView()
{   
    InitializeComponent();
    var data = new NotificationsViewModel();
    this.DataContext = data;
}

А на выходе получаю не заполненные значения, а названия класса.

Соответственно вопрос, в чём может быть проблема, и как заполнить значения значениями, а не названиями класса? Пробовал так же делать через
NotificationInfo.ItemsSource = new NotificationsViewModel().Notifications;

но на выходе получал точно аналогичный вариант

date не равно Date, аналогично Text

Погоды это не изменило, оно всё точно так же не заполняет

Начнем с того, что у вас не может такое писать. Если взять и скопировать весь код из вопроса, то будет такое, то есть, пустота... Если поправить привязки, то будет такое, нормальное отображение всех данных (чтоб про код не думали, вот, прям копия того, что в вопросе). Вывод значит какой делаем? Правильно, вы делаете что-то, что не показываете нам. Возьмите голый WPF проект и на его основе создайте минимальный, самодостаточный пример, который поможет нам воспроизвести проблему.

Это может происходить по той причине, что я в существующим проекте создаю user control? Мне требуется создать xaml и заполнить его, попробовал по вашему примеру сделать на новом проекте с нуля, и всё работает без проблем.

Такой вывод может быть только тогда, когда вы привязываете объект, который не имеет своего отображения, тогда привязка делает объект.ToString() автоматически, что и выводит его тип. Другими словами, в вашем коде такое возможно только если вы напишете не "{Binding Date}", а просто "{Binding}", что привяжет не к значению класса, а к самому классу. Ну вот теперь и смотрите, где у вас такая привязка там находится, может стиль, может сами написали где подобное, ибо как я (да и вы) сказал ранее, такое в текущем виде кода невозможно.

Спасибо, переопределение ToString() хоть как-то облегчило ситуацию, буду продолжать делать через этот костыль.

Это очень плохое решение, советую найти источник вашей проблемы.
